# replace any character except for a given list of characters

Tags: python

```
import re
email=input('Email address? ')
if re.match("^[A-Za-z0-9.@]*$",email):
    print ('valid')
else:
    line = re.sub('anything except for', '', email)
    print ('Not valid')
    print(line)
```

I'm trying to make a simple email verification program with a suggestion if the email isn't valid. In the line line = re.sub is there any way that i can get it to replace any character except for a character that is listed.

Comment: I want it to be the opposite of the list [A-Za-z0-9.@] which i used to decide whether the email was valid or not

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a negated character class.

```
line = re.sub(r'[^A-Za-z0-9.@]', '', email)
```

`[^A-Za-z0-9.@]` would match any character but not of `A-Z` or `a-z` or `0-9` or a dot or `@` . Replacing those characters with an empty string will give you the desired output.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `^` in a character class that match anything except what that came after `^` :

for example if your list was contain `['a','b']`

```
line = re.sub(r'[^ab]', '', email)
```

read more about [Negated Character Classes](http://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html)